# Range with floating point numbers and negative steps

Tags: python, range, generator, yield

I wrote the following for creating a range with negative floating point steps:

```
def myRange(start, stop, step):
    s = start
    if step < 0:
        while s > stop:
            yield s
            s += step
    if step > 0:
        while s < stop:
            yield s
            s += step
```

But the output of `r = myRange(1,0,-0.1)`

looks rather strange

```
>>> r = myRange(1,0,-0.1)
>>> for n in r: print n
... 
1
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
1.38777878078e-16
```

where does this last number come from? And why is it not 0?

Comment: You should learn about [issues with floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You could use `print '%.1f' % n` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) can be represented exactly. For example, this is the output with Python 3.5:

```
1
0.9
0.8
0.7000000000000001
0.6000000000000001
0.5000000000000001
0.40000000000000013
0.30000000000000016
0.20000000000000015
0.10000000000000014
1.3877787807814457e-16
```

One solution could be rounding:

```
def myRange(start, stop, step):
    s = start
    if step < 0:
        while s > stop:
            yield s
            s += step
            s = round(s, 15)
    if step > 0:
        while s < stop:
            yield s
            s += step
            s = round(s, 15)

r = myRange(1,0,-0.1)
for n in r: 
    print(n)
```

Output:

```
1
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
0.0
```